# Не отображаются товары woocommerce + wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

```
Есть сайт на wordpress с плагином woocommerce, в нём уже большое кол-во товаров и категорий, однако есть проблема: при добавлении нового товара через woocommerce api товар не появляется в категории, т.е. его видно в админке и можно открыть по прямой ссылке, однако рядом с другими товарами в своей категории его нет.
Код добавления товара 
`wcapi = API(
    url="url",
    consumer_key="xxx",
    consumer_secret="xxx",
    version="wc/v3",
    timeout=1000,
    verify_ssl=False,
    query_string_auth=True
)

w = wcapi.post('products', data={
        'name': str(i[1]),
        'type': 'simple',
        'regular_price': str(i[2]),
        'description': 'desc',
        'short_description': 'short desc',
        'categories': [
            {'id': str(i[0])}
        ],
        'images': [
            {'src': str(i[3])}
        ],
        'meta_data': [
            {}, {}
        ]
    }).json()
    print(w['id'])`
```

Comment: А какой код добавления нового товара?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/SergeyDertan/0416c4689288f09e02fc043a10115e09

Comment: код лучше вставить в сам вопрос

Comment: Код должен быть в теле вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в ограничении кол-во отображаемых товаров, исправил добавлением данного кода в functions.php

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', function ( $cols ) {
      return 25;
    }, 25 );
```